# Convert from Map (Play framework request.body.asFormUrlEncoded) to case class, and vice versa, with less boilerplate (interacting with untyped world)

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Here is a concrete example, although I have been encountering this problem in the more general case.

I am working on an integration between a Play 2.3 web app and [Slack](https://slack.com/) through a custom slash command. (Note: Slack has docs on the custom slash command API format, but I don't believe I can deep link them directly for a logged-out reader.)

Slack will (when invoked appropriately by a user) POST to my endpoint with standard form URL encoded body with a known format. Their official example is:

```
token=KpADMkoKxZJRGKTG8kJoWXGC
team_id=T0001
team_domain=example
channel_id=C2147483705
channel_name=test
user_id=U2147483697
user_name=Steve
command=/weather
text=94070
```

In my app, I am modeling this request with a case class.

```
case class SlashCommand(
  token: String,
  teamId: String,
  teamDomain: String,
  channelId: String,
  channelName: String,
  userId: String,
  userName: String,
  command: String,
  text: String
)
```

By the way, is there some way to better enforce type constraints other than making each field a `String`?

I am having trouble converting from the Play framework representation of form URL encoded to the case class. Here is the code I have currently, which I believe works correctly, but which I feel is overly repetitive.

```
object SlashCommand {

  def parseFromMap(in: Map[String, String]): Option[SlashCommand] = {
    for {
      token <- in.get("token")
      teamId <- in.get("team_id")
      teamDomain <- in.get("team_domain")
      channelId <- in.get("channel_id")
      channelName <- in.get("channel_name")
      userId <- in.get("user_id")
      userName <- in.get("user_name")
      command <- in.get("command")
      text <- in.get("text")
    } yield SlashCommand(
      token,
      teamId,
      teamDomain,
      channelId,
      channelName,
      userId,
      userName,
      command,
      text
    )
  }

  def parseFromRequest(req: Request[AnyContent]): Option[SlashCommand] = {
    req.body.asFormUrlEncoded.map { m =>
      m.mapValues(_.last)
    }.flatMap(parseFromMap)
  }

}
```

The somewhat repetitive parts that I would ideally like to factor out are:

- explicit `for` with explicit `get`s
- explicit construction of case class
- manual conversion of `Request[AnyContent]` to `Map[String, Option[String]` to `Map[String, String]`

Are there any methods to reduce repetition and improve readability in these conversions?

Additionally, I am likely to need the reverse soon enough, i.e. a conversion from case class to `Map` and/or form URL encoded and/or JSON. Any methods to reduce repetition there?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** I've been thinking about this further, and I think there may be some things I can do using Play framework form handling for the forward case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play Forms API handles binding from `Request`, `Map[String, String]` or `JsValue` to a type of your liking (using `Form.bind` and `Form.bindFromRequest`) and has got a declarative-ish way of describing constraints. So your thinking-edit sounds right to me!

More about the forms API in the Play docs:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms

Comment: It was initially strange to use form handling for non-user input, but this seems to be working well so far. Thanks!